# The group of non zero real or imaginary numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have recently come across with the multiplicative group formed by the union of the real and imaginary axes minus the origin of the complex plane. Surprisingly (at least to me) I couldn't find any information about this group online. I think it may be isomorphic to $$\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{R}^{+},$$where $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is the group of positive reals, but I am not sure. Does anyone have information about this group? Does it have a special name or has it been studied in any context?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The isomorphism you thought of is correct. If you have not done that already I suggest you try to write down the explicit isomorphism to convince yourself you are right. I have never used this group before and am not sure whether it has a specific name.

Comment: More generally, for each positive integer $n$, the set $\{z\in \Bbb C\mid z^n = |z|^n, z \ne 0\}$ will give you a multiplicative group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n \times \Bbb R^+$. Yours is the case for $n = 4$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Now I am trying to see if this group is isomorphic or not to the whole group of units of the complex numbers. I think not, but I am having a hard time proving it. I don't know if it's the best but I was thinking of editing the question to add this part

Comment: I could prove that this are not isomorphic by showing that for a group homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{C}^{*}\rightarrow{\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times{\mathbb{R}^{+}}}$, all the cubic roots of 1 are mapped to 1, hence $\phi$ can never be an iso. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Your guess is right: $\mathbb{C}^*$ contains elements of order $3$, while your group doesn't, so they can't be isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct, and you can realise it as follows: the $n$-roots of unity (i.e. solutions of $x^n = 1$) always form a cyclic group with multiplication: in fact, if $x^n = 1$ then also $(x^n)^2 = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$, and so on. Generators of this cyclic group are called *primitive* roots of unity.

Your case is the special case when $n=4$, in which the roots are $+1, -1, i, -i$. Note that both $i$ and $-i$ are primitive.

Now, to build your group, you are just attaching a copy of $\mathbb{R}^+$ to each root, i.e. you're taking the direct product:

$$\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{R}^+$$

which this time happens to have a nice realization as the axis of the complex plane (but the same construction works for any other $n$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!